# VNC Access on Centos 8

Tags: centos, vnc, tightvnc

I tried to create a vnc session on centos 8 but it showed the below message.

```
Please read /usr/share/doc/tigervnc/HOWTO.md for more information.
```

I followed below instructions,

1. Assigned the port to user.
2. Configure the configuration file
3. Run the vnc service

and when I checked the service wasn't enabled.

Comment: My guess is that one of the three steps was not carried out correctly. Provide more details. I also doubt that this is the only error message you received; after all, it says "for more information", implying that something else was said before. You might also find relevant information in the journal.

Comment: @berndbausch, I went to the vncserver.users file and assigned the port <port>:<user> then went to vncserver-config-defaults file and un-commented the following attributes  securitytypes=vncauth,tlsvnc,
 desktop=sandbox,
 geometry=2000x1200,
 localhost,
 alwaysshared,
 session=gnome, then started the service with this command sudo systemctl start vncserver@:<port no>

Comment: Don't tell me that. Add it to the question.